# I need to filter/copy/fetch only past 3 days data from 30-60 days data set

Tags: python, pandas

I've date variable "interview_start" which holds unique record start date. I just need to filter past 3 days including today's data into another or same dataframe. I've used below code which is working fine but not giving me today's data instead giving me past 3 days. I want to include today's data too.

```
from datetime import datetime

today = date.today()

lastdayfrom = pd.to_datetime(today)

df = df.set_index('interview_start')

df = df.sort_index()

df= df.loc[lastdayfrom - pd.Timedelta(days=4):lastdayfrom].reset_index()
```

how to include today's data too? I've tried (days**<**4) but it is giving me error. However data set is huge with n of variables and data.

Format of interview_Start

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not the most practical approach, but you could loop through the rows in the dataframe, adding each row to a new dataframe, until the date is out of your date range.

I'm going under the assumption you want today data + the three days before e.g. 17/11, 16/11, 15/11, 14/11

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


valid_dates = []
today = datetime.now()
valid_dates.append(today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

for i in range(1, 4):
    valid_dates.append(((today + timedelta(days=-i))).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

You can then loop through your dataframe, adding rows that

```
row['Date'] in valid_dates
```

to your new dataframe.

Comment: Could you please show example if possible..

Comment: I have edited my response for you